# Linker Error while using adtf 2.14.2 lib with C++ on visual studio 15

Tags: c++, linker-errors, adtf

I have adtf 2.14.2 libraries which I am trying to link to my C++ program in visual studio 15 2017 for x64 platform.
I am getting following liker errors

```
2>adtfutild_1170.lib(string.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1900' in adtfFileRead.obj
2>adtfutild_1170.lib(filename.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1900' in adtfFileRead.obj
2>adtfutild_1170.lib(stringlist.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1900' in adtfFileRead.obj
2>adtfutild_1170.lib(filesystem.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1900' in adtfFileRead.obj

. . . .
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: idtb_reader.obj was built with VC++ 14.0, adtfutild_1170.lib with VC++ 10.0. The two are not compatible. (Based on the name, I suspect adtfutild_1170 is from adtf version 1.17.0.)

Comment: idtb_reader.obj is built with visual studio 15. I tried installing Visual Studio 2010 VC++ Redistributable but no help.

Comment: The redistributable runtime libraries have nothing to do with anything. You need a adtfutild library compatible with your compiler.

Comment: My understanding( not sure if correct ) is that if a program/library is built with previous visual studio version and if we need to use it in newer visual studio version then we should install that older versions redistributable. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The redistributables are runtime libraries that other people need to run your application. They have nothing to do with your linker error.

Answer (score 2):

ADTF 2 has been compiled with VS 2010 (VC100). You cannot use it with a compiler higher than this.
You cannot mix that, its compiler/linker incompatible like any other MSVC compiled SDK.

Only ADTF 3 supports VS 2017 (VC141, until ADTF 3.13) and VS 2019 (VC142, since ADTF 3.14), but it is a different major version with breaking changes.

Your only options:

- Porting all your stuff to ADTF 3
- Using MS 2010 (VC100) to compile your custom content

Please note that your project is running to long, ADTF 2 is EOL at the meantime.